# Add Date-Variable to Camunda-BPMN via Rest

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a camunda bpmn workflow where the start-events required some variables.
One of the needed variable is of type 'date':

[image]

```json
{
  "variables": {
    "stichtagFrist": {
      "value": "2021-09-08T00:00:00",
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

now trying to add a new Instance having the above mentioned json, I get the following exception:

`Cannot instantiate process definition d1f43d8e-211f-11ec-8fdf-0242ac110002: Cannot convert value '2021-09-08T00:00:00' of type 'date' to java type java.util.Date"`

How do I need to POST the json that Camunda can interpret it as "date" so that I can use this variable e.g. in timer-events etc.?

Are there any rules for booleans too?

Comment: Which request is that exactly? And have you tried initializing a process instance via form from Camunda cockpit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/7c5bf37307d3eeac3aee5724b6e4669a9992eaba/engine-rest/engine-rest/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/rest/dto/VariableValueDto.java#L109

Uses a Jackson ObjectMapper to parse the value. It requires this format:

```json
{
  "variables": {
    "stichtagFrist": {
      "value": "2021-09-08T00:00:00.0+0000",
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/overview/variables/):

> In the REST API, the type names start with a capital letter, i.e., String instead of string.

Try "Date" instead of "date", that should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately not: ```Cannot convert value '2021-09-08T00:00:00' of type 'Date' to java type java.util.Date"```